# Give name to custom validation Rule - Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-8

Laravel 8 makes it possible to create custom Validation rules: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

`php artisan make:rule Euro`

But then you have to pass the rule as a object (instead of a string):

`new Euro`

instead of the regular string notation

`'required|euro'`

Is there anyway to "register" the new Rule classes to a string identifier and use them like you can you the pre-existing rules?

Comment: you know that it would not change a thing (just make it slower) to achieve this. The string will be used to initiate the rule class and then used.

Comment: There are circumstances where you can't specify validation rules using class instances. Therefore it is a valid question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it the following way.

Create two additional methods in your rule, besides the default ones (`passes()`, `message()`):

- `handle()` -- This one will return your rule's string handle. It's sole purpose is to keep track of that handle in a single place.
- `validate()` -- That's the one which will be invoked by the validator. This should essentially be just a pass through to `passes()` so you can keep your validation logic in one place. Additionally you should pass the message into the validator. In most cases you also want to keep the message logic in one place.

```php
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

public static function handle(): string
{
    return 'euro';
}


public function validate(string $attribute, $value, $params, Validator $validator): bool
{
    $handle = $this->handle();


    $validator->setCustomMessages([
        $handle => $this->message(),
    ]);

    return $this->passes($attribute, $value);
}
```

Register your class using the Validator facade or the factory in a Service Provider's `boot()` method:

```php
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Rules\Euro;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory as ValidatorFactory;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ValidationServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(ValidatorFactory $validator)
    {
        $validator->extend(Euro::handle(), Euro::class);
    }
}
```

That's it.
Don't forget to register your service provider if you created a dedicated one.

Comment: I'm currently no longer working on the project for which I desired this, so I can't trial it. I'll assume it works though :)

Comment: Since your code indicates PHP 8, it is Laravel 9 compatible, right?

Answer (score 5):

This solution work for me.

`php artisan make:rule NoLink`

App\Rules\NoLink.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;

class NoLink implements Rule
{
    // ...

    public function message()
    {
        return __('validation.' . self::handle());
    }

    public static function handle(): string
    {
        return 'no_link';
    }

    public function validate(string $attribute, $value, $params, Validator $validator): bool
    {
        $handle = $this->handle();

        $validator->setCustomMessages([
            $handle => $this->message(),
        ]);

        return $this->passes($attribute, $value);
    }
}
```

App\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

```
    public function boot()
    {
        // ...
        Validator::extend(NoLink::handle(), NoLink::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `extend` function on the validator. Probably something like:

```
Validator::extend('euro', new Euro());
```

This code should be in your AppServiceProvider.

Comment: This doesn't work. I put `dd($value)` in the `Euro`'s `passes()` method, and it never triggers...